# How can I align my images with text in an inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have a side navigation bar, and I have images beside the text, which show the destination of each link. I want the images and their respective link to be side-by-side. Additionally, I want each link's border to be equal. [Here's](http://prntscr.com/msh8kf) how it looks now.

In the first line, I need the guitar icon next to the **Chords** link, and the same for the following links and their icons. Here's the CSS I'm using.

```css
.sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
  transition: width .3s ease;
}

.sidebar a {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(25, 25, 25, .5);
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  transition: background-color .1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
  <img src="img/chords.png">
  <a href="#">Chords</a>
  <img src="img/tabs.png">
  <a href="#">Tabs</a>
  <img src="img/notereading.png">
  <a href="#">Note Reading</a>
</div>
```

I tried setting the position property of the links to *relative*, and this worked for one link. When I inserted the others, however, they did not act as if they were within an inline-block element. That is, they continued on the same line. I thought the inline-block forced elements on the same line only if they could fit, though. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [inline-block](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) is not cause of your problem. Try this HTML instead.

```css
.sidebar {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 60px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .8);
        transition: width .3s ease;
      }
      .sidebar a {
      display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid rgba(25, 25, 25, .5);
        background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
        border-collapse: collapse;
        transition: background-color .1s ease;
        width: 140px;
      }
      .sidebar img {
        transform: translateY(15px);
        width: 50px;
      }
      .sidebar_item {
          height:60px;
          display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar_item">
                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1TkoF1IzxW9y3Xs1YWYpDeX7qCye3ud45" width=55px height=55px>
                <a href="#">Chords</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar_item">
                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1lLkosBRSHmuz6MRN-Vb3UQsX7MrfaX1v" width=55px height=55px>
                <a href="#">Tabs</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar_item">
                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1lLkosBRSHmuz6MRN-Vb3UQsX7MrfaX1v" width=55px height=55px>
                <a href="#">Note Reading</a>
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Actually no, `inline-block` isn't the issue - the OP only uses it on the sidebar. The problem is that `<img>` and `<a>` are inline by default so they will line up horizontally. Wrapping them in a block-level element like a `<div>` makes them stack vertically.

Comment: If we use the html structure by @Ucho and give the additionally added div display: inline-block, it should resolve the problem.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/x5WvNJyntA5UPSMx7     Is that your requirement?

Comment: Yeah @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil that's exactly what I want, except I need the borders of the links to expand to the edge of the sidebar. Currently, it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/msod3u . Additionally, I don't want any space between each link. I can't figure out how to fix that though

Comment: To clarify, that means I don't want the border sizes to be changed by the text length. That's the reason for the differing sizes

Comment: If you are ok with explicit values, you can go on with this.

Comment: Like I said, I don't get the same results with that code. My links' borders are sized based on their text length, which is not what I would like.

Comment: You do get using exactly this snippet you different results?